# Access SQL Sub Query or Associative Array Statement

Tags: ms-access

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
A      1      D         'should be dropped
A      1      K         'should be dropped
B      1      K
B      2      K
A      1      P         'should be dropped
A      2      P
A      1      M         'should be dropped
```

If Field3 = D then ANY ("A" "1") combination should be excluded regardless of Field 3 value. So in this example the first two records should not be returned.

Comment: Only the first record will be considered as that has Field3 = D, but will then be excluded as Field1 = A and Field2 = 1.  `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field3 = 'D' AND (Field1 <> 'A' AND Field2 <>1)`

Comment: My test data was wrong . Thank you Darren but how does that drop record 2?

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT * FROM TableName t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName t2 WHERE t2.Field1=t1.Field1 AND t2.Field2=t1.Field2 AND t2.Field3='D')`?

Comment: Not dealing with two tables (actually about 5).  Actually a series of queries.  First that collects data from one data base, second that collects from current database and a third that compares the two.  I am writing a fourth that looks at the third and finds a Field3 of "D" and then drops any records that match the "D" records Field1 & 2.  I am have a really hard time explaining this.

Comment: It drops record 2 because Field3 = 'K' and not 'D'.

Comment: If does not matter that is "K".  The first two fields match that of a record that was "D" and there for should not be in included.  A sub query is needed or some type of array comparison.  This will not be solved with a simple query.  Thanks for the help all.  I am a network engineer not a programmer.  Going to wait on a local SQL guy to figure this out.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "dropped", but maybe you just want my query in the comment above except using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of `WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: Not included in results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an existing query (we'll call it [TheThirdQuery]) that returns

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  comment
------  ------  ------  -----------------
A            1  D       should be dropped
A            1  K       should be dropped
B            1  K
B            2  K
A            1  P       should be dropped
A            2  P
A            1  M       should be dropped
```

If you want a query that will omit the rows as indicated in the [comment] column (without using the [comment] column itself), that query would be

```sql
SELECT * FROM TheThirdQuery t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TheThirdQuery t2 
    WHERE t2.Field1=t1.Field1 
        AND t2.Field2=t1.Field2 
        AND t2.Field3='D'
    )
```

Comment: After watching some videos on sub queries I learned that what I was doing wrong was passing values back to the outer query incorrectly.  In my case all that was missing was the "EXISTS".  I thought that the outer ran the complete inner for each record in the outer.  Not the case as some of you know.